# Немогу сделать скрипт на Python для конвертации DWG на SVG и наоборот

Tags: python, json, svg, api

Для конвертации я нашел библиотеку Aspose Cad Cloud и написал вот такой код

```
import os
from asposecadcloud import CadApi
import asposecadcloud.models.requests as requests
cad_api = CadApi('key', 'id') // Я их вводил
convertSVGtoDWGRequest = requests.GetDrawingSaveAsRequest(name='circle.svg', output_format='dwg', out_path='circle.dwg', storage='my_storage')
cad_api.get_drawing_save_as(request=convertSVGtoDWGRequest)
```

На что мне дало сразу три ошибки:

```
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

asposecadcloud.rest.ApiException: ('401 Error connecting to the API https://api.aspose.cloud/v3.0/cad/circle.svg/saveAs/dwg; Message: Unauthorized', 401, None)

asposecadcloud.rest.ApiException: ('404 Error connecting to the API https://api.aspose.cloud/v3.0/cad/circle.svg/saveAs/dwg; Message: Not Found', 404, {'code': 'errorItemNotFound',
 'description': 'Operation Failed. Item Not Found.',
 'inner_error': None,
 'message': 'The storage my_storage was not found or is not associated with '
            'the application.'})
```

Есть ли какой-то более простой способ делать такую конвертацию, а если нет, то как мне исправить эти ошибки?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: На форуме aspose заменили storage='MyDB_Storage', может поможет. https://forum.aspose.cloud/t/how-to-convert-dwg-autocad-to-png-in-python-using-aspose-cad-rest-api/9593